# Using django-tastypie for a non-RESTful API

Tags: django, api, rest, tastypie

Suppose you need to write a simple **non-RESTful** API, and want to do it using [django-tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org), how would you do so?

Tastypie only provides `Resource`s that are tightly coupled to a data model.

Is there a way to use tastypie's other utilities for APIs (such as authentication, serlialization, etc.) but use it for "simple" APIs? Of course this could be written as a simple view, but then you'd be missing out on the other stuff tastypie gives you.

A simple example would be an API that receives a string and reverses it.

Comment: You don't need to use the `ModelResource` there's also a `Resource` class you can inherit http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#why-resource-vs-modelresource

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide I never mentioned `ModelResource`, rather `Resource`, and if you take a look, even `Resource` assumes some sort of data model, which I am not interested in. So this doesn't really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of `prepend_urls` - you can add custom endpoints to your existing methods. Out-of-the-box they work just like plain views, but you now have the ability to call all the functions you need from your Resource - and return either plain `HttpResponse`s or piggyback on existing Tastypie functions to return rich objects.

For instance, if I had a `User` resource and wanted to provide an endpoint to determine if a user is currently authenticated by returning `1` or `0`, I'd do this:

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        #...
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/is_authenticated?$" % (self._meta.resource_name), self.wrap_view('is_authenticated')),
        #...
    ]
# ...other methods in your Resource...
def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
    if self._meta.authentication.is_authenticated(request):
        return HttpResponse("1")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("0")
```

Or, if I actually wanted to return the actual user resource for the authenticated user, I could (for example) replace `return HttpResponse("1")` with `return self.get_detail(request, id=request.user.id)` - effectively simulating a call to `/user/?id=[authenticated user's ID]`.